# Parent Object is not populated while creating a Child Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am playing around with **SpringBoot** lately along with **Spring data jpa**. Here's the thing. I have two classes Teacher and Course where there exists a OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship between them respectively. Course is a owning side of this relationship as seen below:

```
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = CourseSerializer.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "teacher", "students" }, allowGetters = true)
public class Course {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Getter @Setter
private Long id;
@Getter @Setter
private String title;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Getter
@Setter
private Teacher teacher;
....
}
```

And Teacher class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "courses" }, allowGetters = true)
public class Teacher {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Getter @Setter
private Long id;
@Getter @Setter
@JsonProperty("first_name")
private String firstName;
@Getter @Setter
@JsonProperty("last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL /*another problem: , fetch = EAGER*/)
@JsonSerialize(converter = ListCourseConverter.class)
@Getter @Setter
private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
....
}
```

Now Course cannot exist without a Teacher (optional=false). I am trying to make a POST call for the course creation this way to /api/course/teacherId:

```
{
"title": "Java Complete"
}
```

And I am expecting the following result from the call:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Java Complete",
"teacher": "<firstName> <lastName>"
}
```

For this reason, I am using a CourseSerializer which serializes the Teacher object to display just that:

```
...
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.getId());
        jgen.writeStringField("title", value.getTitle());
        jgen.writeStringField("teacher", value.getTeacher().getFirstName() + " " + value.getTeacher().getLastName());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
...
```

But interestingly, I am seeing "null null" for the teacher field. My Controller -> Service looks like this for the above operation:

```
CourseController.java
---------------------
    @PostMapping("/{teacherId}")
    public Course createCourse(@RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable("teacherId") Long teacherId) {
        course.setTeacher(new Teacher(teacherId));
        return courseService.createCourse(course);
    }

CourseService.java
------------------
    public Course createCourse(Course course) {
        return courseRepository.save(course);
    }
```

So...

**Problem 1)** While doing course.getTeacher() for the returned object I see only ID field is populated. I have also tried changing the fetch type for the teacher field in Course class, making a findOne(course.getId()) call after the save(...) operation but doesn't work. But interestingly I see the proper result if I make a GET request after the earlier POST call. So, why am I not able to see the complete data in Course during POST since it is mapped with Teacher already?

**Problem 2)** Delete operation on Course does not work when the courses are set to fetch in EAGER fashion under Teacher class but works fine for LAZY fetch.

Comment: there is no parent-child relationship between course and teacher, it's composition.

Comment: In JPA terms, can't we say there is one? because I saw couple of blogs referring that way to O2M mappings.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use all those JSON properties if you use DTOs to receive and response.

`course.setTeacher(new Teacher(teacherId));` this is not a good practice at all

use one and point to create the course, other to create the teacher.
after that, you can create a put method to update the course with the teacher

```
 @PutMapping("/{courseId}/{teacherId}")
public Course addTeacherToCourse( @PathVariable("courseId") Long courseId,@PathVariable("teacherId") Long teacherId) {
    return courseService.addTeacherToCourse(courseId,teacherId);
}
```

the course service should validate the courseID and teacherID and if they exist then update and save them.

[here](https://github.com/jeanschuchardt/school) you can look at my example based on your code.

Comment: I don't understand. I am having a similar structure where Teacher is created in one API and Course in another. It's just that during Course creation, Persistent layer require an ID for the Teacher entry which is done by setting new Teacher(teacherId). There is no additional PUT call. Your implementation would make a ton of DB calls since you are coupling TeacherRepository alongside CourseRepository in your Service implementation which is very bad in terms of performance whereas my code would simply save a Course which in turn would update the FK with Teacher and check if the Teacher exists.